# How to keep text over a huge image in proper position on all resolutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my intro page I have a really big image in height and width to fit all the resolutions (more than 4000px in width) and I set it as below:

```
#source-image {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Then, I added some text over that image with these style properties:

```
.description {
    position:absolute;
    top:510px;  
    left:23px;
    width:340px
}
```

And it looks properly (and as I want it to be shown) on my 15.6 inch laptop with 1366x768 resolution.

[image]

However when my roommate saw it on his high resolution monitor the description was not on the “right” position. Of course, I understand why this is happening.

[image]

My question is how can I keep dynamically the proper position of the description text in all resolutions?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Use bottom instead of top on the blue div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the distance from the bottom, not from the top. Or set it in %.

**EDIT**: I've adapted one of my experiments into an example: http://dabblet.com/gist/2787061 
The position of the description is set relative to the `bottom` and the `left` of the image container (the image is filling its entire container).

In the first case, the distances to the `left` and the `bottom` of the image container are fixed, in px.

In the second case, they are in % and change on resizing the browser window.

Basically, the rules that do the trick are

```
figcaption {
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 23px;
        /* more rules here */
}
```

in the fist case (fixed distances, in px) and

```
figcaption.perc {
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 17%;
}
```

in the second case (percentage).

Also, please note that you don't need `position: absolute` or to set the `top` and the `left` properties for the image.
However, you do need to set `position:relative` on the parent of the description box.

---

For the image to fill the screen *horizontally*, you need to have `margin:0;` and `padding:0;` on the body element and `width: 100%;` and `margin: 0;` on the figure element. I've edited my example to reflect these changes http://dabblet.com/gist/2787061

For the image to fill the screen *both horizontally and vertically*, the easiest way is to not even use an img tag, but simply set the image as a background image for the body and set the height for both the html and the body elements to 100% - example http://dabblet.com/gist/2792929

Be careful for two reasons: one, this will really distort the image and can make it look ugly when resizing the browser window and two, if you need some content below the image you will need to give the the outer element `position: absolute` and set its `top: 100%`. Both these two aspects can be seen in the example I've linked to. You can simply remove the content below the image if you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you for this but how does the image fits completely the screen? Because now there is an area on all sides

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain that - see the last three paragraphs (below the horizontal line).

Comment: I really thank you and I appreciate your help. I have one last question though. Despite the fact that the `figcaption` works great on all resolutions, I have to have another one block on `left:830px`. This is quite right on my 1366 resolution laptop. However, this looks awkward in bigger and smaller resolutions (and in some disappears). In all cases the `figcaption` appears correctly.

Comment: You could set a % value to the right instead of left - try starting with something like `right: 3%`, see how it looks using different resolutions, tweak the 3% value up or down. You could even try using relative units for the blocks.

Answer (score 1):

use `position:relative;` for the div that wraps the image, and `position:absolute;` for the text div

Answer (score 0):

please set percentage

check the example- description box set in horizontal center,

first set position relative into wraper div

```
.description {
    position:absolute;
    top:510px;  
    left:50%;
    width:340px;
    margin:0 0 0 -170px
}
```